# Is there any way to ALTER a column to switch off 'NOT NULL'?

Tags: sql-server

Can this be done in bulk too? So that all columns in the table can be set to switch off the 'NOT NULL' flag?

Comment: for a MSSQL database just to clarify ;)

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? Will make a difference to the ideal script to go through them all...

Comment: I'm concerned as to why anyone would want to do this in bulk. I would never consider a change of this magnitude without examining the impact on every part of my system, you can break alot of stuff when suddenly allowing nulls where they weren't before. And there is usually a reason why the field does not allow nulls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use an ALTER TABLE xxx ALTER COLUMN statement to redefine the column.

---

If this is a one-time thing you need to run, you could use a trick by writing a query that queries the column names for the table from the system/dba table and generates your alter statements. You copy the results of the query (your 15 or however many alter statements) into your script and just run that. I don't have much mssql experience nor an environment to test on right now but something along the lines of:

```
SELECT 
  'ALTER TABLE ' + table_name + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + column_name + ' ' + data_type
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'xxx'
```

where you will need to manipulate the data_type part to add/remove the NULL constraint text

Comment: Cool, is there any way this could be done in a loop to go through each column of the table? If yes, then can you explain / show code?

Comment: The above query will output several ALTER TABLE scripts, one for each column. Executing each, one after another, will alter all the columns

Answer (score 1):

To do it in bulk, once...

Use SSMS designer to generate a script. This will rebuild your table (create a temp table, copy data, drop old table, rename temp table).

Otherwise, it's one at a time using ALTER TABLE...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Read books online.

No, it can't be done in bulk, but you could execute several statements in a single query.

Comment: The problem is that the table has sooo many columns this would take forever :(

Comment: Well, if the table has so many columns that you cannot do it manually, then you should *really* rethink your table desing :-(. Anyway, you could script the ALTER statement, either in T-SQL (should be doable), or just write a script which generates the ALTER-statements.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of the columns and a template that has the required SQL and use some tool to create the statements for you. 
I have done this in Excel before, but you could write a real program using your language of choice.

Answer (score 0):

When the number of tables is low enough I'm using SSMSE (SQL Server Management Studio Express), by entering design mode on each table and checking **Allow Nulls** on the required columns.

For a larger number of tables, try the answer provided by **ChrisCM**.